# Multiple value insert into single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, multiple-value

I need help for query two table become a table

The first table, **Tbl_Project:**

```
|ID     | Category  | Freq_Project|
|-------|---------- |-------------|
|12001  |   x_GM    | 1           |
|12001  |   x_PP    | 1           |
|12001  |   x_RI    | 1           |
|12001  |   x_SS    | 3           |
```

The second table, **Tbl_Activity:**

```
|ID     | Category  | Freq_Activity|
|-------|---------- |--------------|
|12001  |   x_GM    |4             |
|12001  |   x_PP    |3             |
|12001  |   x_SA    |2             |
|12001  |   x_RI    |2             |
```

And, I want the result looks like this

```
|ID     | Category  | Freq_Activity | Freq_Project|
|-------|---------- |---------------|-------------|
|12001  |   x_GM    |   4           |   1         |
|12001  |   x_PP    |   3           |   1         |
|12001  |   x_SA    |   2           |   **Null**  |
|12001  |   x_RI    |   2           |   1         |
|12001  |   x_SS    |   **Null**    |   3         |
```

How should I make this query ?

Comment: Result you want is produced by simple full join. Try to learn some basics.

Comment: full join only effect for single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to insert the result in target table.

```
Insert INTO ResultTable(ID,Category,Freq_Activity,Freq_Project,Tbl_Project)
Select ISNULL(P.ID,A.ID),ISNULL(P.Category,A.Category),A.Freq_Activity,P.Freq_Project,Tbl_Project
from Tbl_Project P
FULL OUTER JOIN Tbl_Activity A
ON P.ID=A.ID
AND P.Category = A.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

A full join looks like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(P.ID,A.ID),ISNULL(P.Category,A.Category),P.Freq_Projeckt,A.Freq_activity
FROM Tbl_Project P
FULL OUTER JOIN Tbl_Activity A
ON A.ID=P.ID AND A.Category=P.Category
```

Comment: Close. Add two coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

Using Union :

```
        SELECT distinct ID,Category,max(Freq_Activity)Freq_Activity,
        max(Freq_Project)Freq_Project  from
        (
        SELECT ID,Category,Freq_Project,null 'Freq_Activity'
        FROM Tbl_Project TP
        union
        SELECT ID,Category,null 'Freq_Project',Freq_Activity
        FROM Tbl_Activity TP
        )a
        group by ID,Category
```